# How to say that a mathematical curve contains a point?

Tags: word-request, mathematics

What would be the suitable Latin verb to express the idea that a curve (e.g. a circle, a parabola) contains/includes a point?

My first thought was

> parabola punctum continet

but it seems that *contineo* and *includo* are closer to bound, restrain, etc. than to include as we use it in English.

*Edit.* [la.wikipedia.org](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctum_(mathematica)) uses *continet* but the site is not know to be very good Latin.

Comment: How you say this might depend on how much you care about the idea that a curve is a point-set. There are foundational approaches like smooth infinitesimal analysis (SIA) in which the opposite is true: one can prove that a curve *can't* consist of a set of points. A phrasing like the one in Draconis's answer can be used if you're willing to sidestep that issue. I believe the symbol ∈ comes from Greek epsilon, as an abbreviation for ἐστι (is), the idea being that if a is blue, then we can express this as a∈B, where B is the set of blue things.

Comment: I was thinking of the Euclidian definitions, a curve is basically an extended point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you seemed to be open to Draconis' suggestions, I gather you are not wed to the set-theory idea of a line "containing" a point and are just looking for a way to say the point *is on* the line (i.e., it is either one of the line's end points or the line goes through it).

In that case, I would suggest: *punctum in parabola situm est* (*situs, -a, -um* = placed). Why? Because in such cases my go-to method is to Google what Euler has to say, and Euler has, for example, this to say:

> Illustrissimus Auctor ostendit tria horum punctorum E, F et H semper in eadem linea recta fore sita
>
> si tria puncta E, F, G forment triangulum EFG, tum quartum punctum H ita in recta EF producta [drawn out, extrapolated] erit situm, ut sit FH = 1/2 EF
>
> Casus quo quatuor puncta in directum sunt sita

All examples taken from [Solutio facilis problematum quorundam geometricorum difficillimorum](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/325/).

(Sub quo titulo inconspicuo latet una e multis rebus ab Eulero nomen tenentibus, [Recta Euleri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line).)

Comment: I also looked for Euler's way to say it but didn't find this text, anyway this is a perfect answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It requires rearranging the sentence, but how about *jaceō* or *sedeō* with a preposition: "the point *lies on* the curve"?

Comment: This could work, do you have any reference for it?

Comment: ...or simply *sum*.